# How does this ShaderToy create Cyan from Red?

Tags: glsl

Run it here: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/Mtsfzs

Source of Buf A:

```
vec4 getPixel(in vec2 xy)
{ return texture(iChannel0, xy);
}

vec4 getPixelBlurredB(in vec2 xy)
{  
return (getPixel(xy)+getPixel(xy + 1./iResolution.xy) )/2.;
}

void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    vec2 xy = fragCoord.xy/iResolution.xy; 
    vec4 c;

    c = getPixel( xy*.99 );      // Zoom in
    c -= getPixelBlurredB( xy*.99 )/4.; // Darken interior more than boundary
    c *= 1.3;                    // Brighten
    c -= 0.0001;                  // Darken - dark more

    if(fragCoord.x==.5 && fragCoord.y==.5 /*precarious*/)
        c=vec4(1.,0.,0.,0.);

    fragColor = clamp(c,-0.1,1.); //-ve causes cyan!s

}
```

Source of Image:

```
void mainImage( out vec4 fragColor, in vec2 fragCoord )
{
    fragColor = texture(iChannel0, fragCoord.xy/iResolution.xy);
}
```

Output: 
[image]

The pattern seed is colour R=1, G=0, B=0 and is processed by code that does not add to G or B, and so I would expected the output to show only red. But the output shows cyan too, indicating G and B channels have somehow become non-zero. How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
c -= 0.0001;
fragColor = clamp(c,-0.1,1.);
```

The first line subtracts a small value from all components, not just the red. The second line clamps the resulting color into a range between -0.1 and 1.0. Assuming that a bright red color is sampled, this results in this output: `vec4(1.0, -0.0001, -0.0001, -0.0001)`. Because negative values can't be displayed, when presenting this color to the screen, it's clamped to a (0.0, 1.0) range, resulting in a pure red color. But the negative values are still present in the buffer.

```
c = getPixel( xy*.99 );
c -= getPixelBlurredB( xy*.99 )/4.;
```

Now, if we consider a case where the current pixel is black, but the one sampled by `getPixelBlurredB()` has our slightly negative color, the resulting `c` after clamping would look something like: `vec4(-0.1, 0.0001, 0.0001, 0.0001)`, barring the scaling. This produces a very faint cyan color, too faint to display properly, but it's there. It eventually gets amplified enough to become visible by progressively sampling and multiplying it in each iteration. You can prove this amplification works by initializing the corner value as `vec4(0.0001, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`. Eventually it produces the exact same pattern, it just takes longer to start off. This is also why you only see red at first.

As further proof, replacing the subtraction with `c.r -= 0.0001` only produces red as expected, `c.rg -= 0.0001` shows red and green instead of red and cyan, and `c.rb -= 0.0001` ends up as red and blue.

Comment: Thanks. So the root problem is invalid colour values produced by the subtractions. Clamping either subtraction's result is sufficient to solve the visible problem, and one could say for robustness one should clamp both: https://www.shadertoy.com/view/llffDS .